# Using variables in DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Is there any way to make this work in IE8?:

```
spacer = 0.5;
elem.setAttribute("style", "margin: 0%" + spacer + "%");
```

It works in Chrome, FireFox, and even in IE.11, but works in IE8 if the variable is not used:

```
elem.setAttribute("style", "margin: 0% 0.5%");
```

Thank you.

Comment: `elem.setAttribute("style", "margin: 0% " + spacer + "%");` You missed space

Comment: Doh! Your're right. Thank you Satpal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use equivalent

```
elem.style.margin = '0 ' + spacer + '%';
```

Just for info, your problem was in missing space.

Comment: I always get confused with the various forms of DOM. Thank you for this one. Does any one method have any advantage over another?

Comment: Advantage of using standard DOM properties was mainly in the past, in IE7- wasn´t possible to set styles using setAttribute - http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t1210. Now there is no problem, for me, my code looks better (just my view).